# Validation of data entered by the user in c

Tags: c, regex, validation

I have problem. The user types a command, which is stored in the cmd variable. The first four characters in the command are non-variable. I retrieve all characters starting from the fourth one. The retrieved characters are passed to the variable check.

This is where the biggest problem arises. I would like to make it so that the program checks for a valid string. The only valid string is |3| but there can be many such strings, for example |4|30| or |15|1|100| and so on to infinity. The most important thing is that the user between two | characters can only enter numbers in decimal format.

I have created a regex, but it doesn't work because even the decimal number alone without the | characters gives a positive result. For there to be a positive result there must be two | characters and a decimal number between them. How can I make the program work properly?

```
#include "stdarg.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    char cmd[] = "WBRA|5|80|120|3|40|";
    int length = strlen(cmd);
    char check[100];
    int index = 0;
    
    for(int i=4; i<length; i++){
        check[index++] = cmd[i];
    }
    
    printf("%s\n\r", check);
    regex_t regex;
    int return_value;
    return_value = regcomp(&regex,"(\\|\\d*\\|){n}",0);
    return_value = regexec(&regex, "check", 0, NULL, 0);
    printf("Result %d\n\r", return_value); // 0 is correct

}
```

Comment: You can try with `regcomp(&regex,"^\\|(\\d+\\|)+$",REG_EXTENDED)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not working because |5|80|120|3|40| return 1

Comment: It is working, there is another issue.

Comment: Rocky Balboa, `printf("%s\n\r", check);` is not good as `check` is not a _string_.

Comment: `check[index++] = cmd[i];` also risks buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the two lines in your code to

```c
return_value = regcomp(&regex,"^\\|([0-9]+\\|)+$",REG_EXTENDED);
return_value = regexec(&regex, check, 0, NULL, 0);
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/np4k9L).

*Details*:

- The regex must be `^\|([0-9]+\|)+$` that matches a whole string that starts with a `|` char and then contains one or more occurrences of one or more digits and a `|` char till the end
- `REG_EXTENDED` is required for this pattern to work correctly
- You used `"check"` rather than `check` in the `regexec` command (so you were checking the regex against `check` word and not the `|5|80|120|3|40|` string).

Comment: Wow. This is working. Master class. Thank you very much. I love you :D

Comment: Note: `check` is not a _string_ so `regexec(&regex, check, 0, NULL, 0);` is not certain to work.